# Where to load unmutable data from database in a Django project?

Tags: django, django-models

I was wondering what the right place would be to load an unmutable piece of data from the database which should be available in all models.

It is basically a database-wide setting (rather than project setting), but should interface similar to a data model and should be accessible in other models as well.

Where do I put/implement this? This, well, somewhat architectural question is not quite clear from the documentation I have read.

EDIT:
Setting:
I'm using a graph DB, not relational DB. Have a node called "current" which points to the current versions of pieces of versioned data as a shortcut. When updating a piece of data (a node) the deletion of the relationship to the old node and linking the new node is taken care of in the respective node's model when calling .save().

There is exactly one "current" node which points to every node containing up-to-date date, newest versions. This node itself is unmutable. It has no properties. Its relationships are managed by the linked nodes' models.

Because it's a singleton (as a concept, not necessarily a Singleton class implementation), it would be a waste of DB ressources to query it every time, hit the DB every time.

Does that clarify the matter? Thanks!

Comment: Would something like this project help? https://github.com/andres-torres-marroquin/django-system-globals

Comment: Why do you want "unmutable" data in the database? What about having a base model with a property loaded from django settings?

Comment: @tuxcanfly: good point, I'll elaborate on the question in an edit.

Comment: @Jacinda: while it does not help directly, it's cache implementation really helped me, which I'll learn from and which I can prolly use. If you add your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not the exact implementation of a solution to your exact problem, this project manages system globals from a database.  It contains a cache implementation that may help you avoid querying the database every time in your project.

https://github.com/andres-torres-marroquin/django-system-globals/blob/master/system_globals/models.py